# Disabling input fields using jquery when username already exist

Tags: jquery, html

This is my jquery script to check for the duplicate username and throw out the error using ajax.I want to disable all other fields when i get duplication.That is below in the else statement under username is already available.I want to disable all other fields when this message appears.I have attached my form html below the jquery script.I already tried this (   $("#details").attr("disabled",true);) but not working.Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#username').keyup(function(){// Keyup function for check the user action in input
            var Username = $(this).val(); // Get the username textbox using $(this) or you can use directly $('#username')
            var UsernameAvailResult = $('#username_avail_result'); // Get the ID of the result where we gonna display the results
            if(Username.length > 2) { // check if greater than 2 (minimum 3)
                UsernameAvailResult.html('Loading..'); // Preloader, use can use loading animation here
                var UrlToPass = 'action=username_availability&username='+Username;
                $.ajax({ // Send the username val to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
                type : 'POST',
                data : UrlToPass,
                url  : 'checker.php',
                success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
                    if(responseText == 0){
                        UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="success">Username name available</span>');
                    }
                    else if(responseText > 0){
                        UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="error">Username already taken</span>');


                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Problem with sql query');
                    }
                }
                });
            }else{
                UsernameAvailResult.html('Enter atleast 3 characters');
            }
            if(Username.length == 0) {
                UsernameAvailResult.html('');
            }
        });


    });
```

---

- HTML:

  Name:
            *

  ```
        </label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-input col-md-9">
      <input id="username" name="customer_name" placeholder="Name" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
           <td><div class="username_avail_result" id="username_avail_result"></div></td>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label col-md-3">
      <label for="details">
        Details :
        <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-input col-md-9">
      <input id="details" placeholder="details" name="customer_details" value="" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label col-md-3">
      <label for="domain">
        Domain :
        <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-input col-md-9">
      <input id="domain" placeholder="Domain" name="domain" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label col-md-3">
      <label for="vertical">
        Vertical :
        <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-input col-md-9">
      <input id="vertical" placeholder="Vertical" name="vertical" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label col-md-3">
      <label for="taxonomy">
        Taxonomy :
        <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    <div class="form-input col-md-9">
      <input id="taxonomy" placeholder="Taxonomy" name="taxonomy" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
   <input type="submit" class="btn medium primary-bg" id="new-customer-valid" name="submit" onclick="javascript:$('#new-customer').parsley( 'validate' );" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  ```

Comment: $elment.attr('disabled', 'disabled') will work

Comment: tried its not worked.Got the answer already

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery version `>=1.6` then you need to use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()`:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

```
$("#details").prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to disable all other fields when i get duplication.*

You can update to this:

```
else if(responseText > 0){
   UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="error">Username already taken</span>');
   $('form').find(':input').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
}//-^^^^^^^--you can place your form's id here
```

---

What this is doing?

First you get to your form and `:input` will select all the input elements in your form `.not(this)` will exclude the current element you are working on then you have to use `.prop()` method which is strongly recommended. you can look at the [documentation for .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName).

#### From the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method.

---

or you can give a try to this:

```
$(this).closest('form').find(':input').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("input['text']").attr("disabled",true);
```